# Writing Combinations Recursively using ArrayList of Integers in Java

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, combinations

so I am quite close in solving this algorithm. This is part of another lengthier algorithm, I just made this one to find every possible ordered combination of integers in an ArrayList.

I have an ArrayList of integers {0, 1, 2}. I want to efficiently use recursion to solve for this, using the member method permute(). I have the original ArrayList {0, 1, 2} and use ArrayList preArr to fill it one by one using ArrayList helper until preArr has filled up items, then try to clear both preArr and helper to refill with a new combination.

```
public class ArrayPermutation {

    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayPermutation(int N) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr.add(i);
            //System.out.println("Arr at index " + i + " ===> " + arr[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test an integer array and pring all posible combinations
        int N = 3;
        ArrayPermutation a = new ArrayPermutation(N);
        a.solver(N);
    }

    public void solver(int N) {
        ArrayList<Integer> pArr = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> preArr = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
           pArr.add(i);
        }
        permute(preArr, pArr, N);
    }

    public void permute(ArrayList<Integer> preArr, ArrayList<Integer> pArr, int N) {

        int n = pArr.size();
        ArrayList<Integer> helper = new ArrayList<>();

        if(n == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < preArr.size(); i++) {
                System.out.print(preArr.get(i) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if(j == i)
                    {
                        preArr.add(pArr.get(j));
                    } 
                    else {
                        helper.add(pArr.get(j));
                    }

                }
                permute(preArr, helper, N);
                preArr.clear();
                helper.clear();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

From here, I have the following.

```
Expected Output
0 1 2
0 2 1
1 0 2
1 2 0
2 0 1
2 1 0

Actual Output
0 1 2 
2 1 
1 0 2 
2 0 
2 0 1 
1 0
```

So as you can see I am missing the very first integer from every second list. I know I'm close, I am just having some trouble figuring out this one particular problem. I have already looked at some help using other sources, but it is a bit tricky to figure out my specific example. I appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're clearing `preArr` before you're done with that set of permutations.  You probably want to remove the last element instead.

Comment: Wow! So I replaced preArr.clear() with preArr.remove(preArr.size()-1) and it worked! I feel a bit dumber, but relieved now, thanks for pointing that out, it helped me of possibly longer time of figuring it out on my own.